# Why does "if" seem to halt a recursive call in NetLogo?

Tags: recursion, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

A problem seems to arise from a simple exercise dealing with recursive procedures in NetLogo 5.x.  The model simulates turtles wandering one patch at a time and gathering M&Ms from the patches. The goal is to use a recursive procedure call to allow turtles who DO find an M&M to get two additional turns. This can be easily done with a non-recursive approach in which we use a variable to track the number of turns. However, we need to use recursion in this case, and recursion seems to cause an inexplicable problem:

```
patches-own [MM]
turtles-own [collection]

to setup ;; observer
  ca
  random-seed 1234
  ask patches [ set MM random 6 ]
  ask patches [ set plabel-color grey - 3 
                set plabel MM ]
  crt 10 [ set color grey 
                       set heading (random 4 * 90) 
                       set collection 0 
                       set label-color yellow ]
end


to go ;; observer
 ask turtles [ collect ]
 if max [ MM ] of patches = 0 [ stop ]
end

to collect ;; turtles 
 rt (90 * random 4)
 fd 1

 if [ MM ] of patch-here > 0
  [ set collection collection + 1
   set MM MM - 1 
   set label collection
   set plabel  MM
   collect
   collect
  ]
end
```

Were this code to function correctly two sub-instances of collect should be spawned and run each time a turtle comes across an M&M. This may be happening, however, what happens is that turtles stop their collecting spree as soon as they hit patch with zero M&Ms.  As a result, this code produces the same result as when collect only calls itself once, as well as when collect calls itself three or more times.

This leads me to believe that the `if` conditional within which the recursion is running might be causing the problem because putting the recursive call outside the conditional will work. NetLogo seems not to respect the recursion in some way. For example, if you insert debugging code around the `collect collect` lines at the end of the procedure:

```
   show "!"
   collect
   show "two"
   collect
   show "three"
  ]
show "four"
end
```

then only `!` and `four` print to the command center, but the others never execute. Any help on why this works this way would be useful.  Seems more like bug than a feature.

Comment: I think **IF** may cause problems with brackets. a parser error

Answer (score 0):

If you hit a patch with no MM's there is no recursive call, the collect procedure moves the turtles and ends.  Your recursive calls are inside the body of the if clause, if the condition is false, you skip over them.

Comment: So if a turtle finds an M&M on its first `collect`, that should trigger two additional `collect` procedures. If the first of those two is unsuccessful, the turtle won't immediately implement the second one?

Comment: You can test your hypothesis yourself by inserting print statements in your code and seeing how it behaves.

Comment: looks like he did above.